# Помогите с формулой в Google sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet, формулы, импорт

Есть сайт = https://xn--80aaig9ahr.xn--c1avg/manga/the_beginning_after_the_end?subpath=content
Там я смотрю мангу при переходе на сайт видна таблица где пишется какая часть вышла. Как импортировать или поправить формулу которая бы импортировала число. На данный момент на сайте есть первое число 20. Это число мне нужно импортировать в гугл таблицу в виде формулы. Только число и нечего более.

Формулу которую я использую - =REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(INDIRECT("R[-1]C";0);"table";0);2;1);"\d+\s*(?:-\s*)?(\S+)")

Или же есть таблица где я храню подобные формулы - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16rX9mhuwphaysjlnXDJfk3y2u-1LQnpl8r1SmyL5CWU/edit?usp=sharing

Сайты на котором эти формулы работают
https://readmanga.live/ia_stal_grafskim_ubliudkom
https://mintmanga.live/killing_blooms_under_the_rounded_moon

Есть ли люди которые помогут мне. Буду очень сильно благодарен. Потому что до меня не доходит как это сделать.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что Вам нужен самый первый (верхний) **номер главы** в списке глав со страницы https://xn--80aaig9ahr.xn--c1avg/manga/the_beginning_after_the_end?subpath=content ?

Comment: Да на данный момент это число 24.

Answer (score 0):

Указанный Вами сайт отдает данные не напрямую в коде HTML, а формирует их скриптом динамически. Иначе говоря, нужные Вам номера глав приходят с другого URL и скрипт вставляет их на страницу после получения на сторону клиента. Небольшое исследование показывает, что "другой URL" на самом деле такой: https://api.remanga.org/api/titles/chapters/?branch_id=852 и с него можно получить требуемые данные в формате JSON, они начинаются примерно так:

```
{"msg":"","content":[{"id":426298,"tome":3,"chapter":"24","name":"Похолодало","score":1106,...
```

Номер последней главы (в данном случае - 24) находится сразу после первого слова "chapter", его можно извлечь с помощью регулярного выражения, например так:

```
/chapter":"(\d+)/
```

Вместить всю эту логику в формулу все же можно, но лучше использовать для этого свой скрипт:

```
function LAST_CHAPTER() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.remanga.org/api/titles/chapters/?branch_id=852');
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var content = response.getContentText();
    var m = content.match(/chapter":"(\d+)/);
    if (m != null) return m[1];
  }
  return '?';
}
```

Заметим, что из JSON-кода можно извлечь не только номер последней главы, но и ее название, идентификатор и прочее. Про идентификатор, конечно, вопроса не было, но раз уж углубились в тему получения данных с ресурса, то скажем и про него. Главе 24 сопоставлен идентификатор 426298, а по адресу https://xn--80aaig9ahr.xn--c1avg/manga/the_beginning_after_the_end/ch426298 можно читать саму главу. Видимо, далее ясно.

И последнее замечание. Вписанная в ячейку формула `=LAST_CHAPTER()` не будет автоматически пересчитываться при появлении новых глав. Требуется придумать механизм принудительного обновления данных в этой ячейке. Вероятно, проще будет запускать отдельный скрипт по расписанию, а уж этот скрипт будет Вас уведомлять доступными способами.